WebStorm imports from HTML
When I import from HTML a Enum/Const the protected readonly that WebStorm produces is at the bottom of the TS; Is there an option to set the protected readonly above the constructor?
Code example
HTML:
<svg-icon [name]="Icon.Arrow" />

TypeScript:
export class TestComponent  {

  constructor() {
  }

  protected readonly Icon = Icon;
}

I checked in "Editor > Code Style > TypeScript", and I didn't find away to change the place.
To clarify, I want the Icon code to be above the constructor like this:
export class TestComponent  {

  protected readonly Icon = Icon;

  constructor() {
  }
}


I don't think so. Generated code will adhere to the formatting options but there's nothing about order of methods/properties. If it helps, you can click on the property and use Ctrl + Shift + ↑ to easily move it.
